# How to include services from an npm module in Sails.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I have some utility services I want to package into a node module for include in multiple Sails.js projects.

I know that any files included in the `api\services\` directory gets included on the global scope automatically.

How do I include a service on the global scope from a node module, not located in the services folder?

I don't want to link them with grunt or make any kind of copy, either. I actually have grunt disabled for my projects.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to create a Sails.js [hook](http://sailsjs-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/concepts/userhooks/). You can generate a basic hook with the [hook generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-generate-hook).

Answer (score 1):

I tend to simply refer to the libraries in my services folder. This is a utilService.js I use for a bunch of libraries.

api/services/utilService.js

```
var changeCase = require("change-case"),
    moment = require("moment"),
    numeral = require("numeral");

module.exports = {
    numeral : numeral, 
    moment : moment, 
    changeCase : changeCase
}
```

Now each of these libraries are referenced globally:

```
utilService.numeral()
utilService.moment()
utilService.changeCase()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this module to make your hook, it load custom controllers, models and services from user hook 
https://github.com/jaumard/sails-util-mcvsloader

Comment: Since 0.11.0 ([changelog](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/0.11-migration-guide.md#user-level-hooks)), user hooks can now be installed directly from NPM. Could you write more precisions on what your solution offer that is not handle by Sails.js itself?

Comment: Yes hooks can be install from npm but what if you want Models/Controllers/Services embedded on your hook ? That's the sails-util-mcvsloader module do. You can put your own model/controller/service on multiple sails project with this. And they can be override on your sails project if you need.

Comment: sails-util-mcvsloader can be use on an installable hook, I put an example on the repository if you want to look.